# Android - Return to Main Activity when app left

Tags: android, android-activity

Currently my app has a login screen, the main activity, and three other activities. All of these should only be accessed once the user has logged in, using the main activity. At the moment, if the user presses the overview or home button and later comes back to the app, the page that the user was on when they left will load, regardless of whether it should. I'm trying to find a way of returning the app to the main activity once the user leaves, not closes, the app.

The only method I've found so far is by starting the main activity through an intent via `onPause()`, however, this does load the main activity but retains focus on the app whereas the system function of the home or overview button should be enacted.

I would provide code but I don't know that anything I have would be relevant.

Hopefully someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the desired behaviour use the [android:noHistory="true"](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist) attribute under the `activity` tag of `AndroidManifest.xml` for the *"three other activities"*.

But **note!** that in this case the *"three other activities"* won't be kept in the backstack, so pressing the back button from within any of the activities will bring you to the main one.

A solution to preserving the "back-button-press" navigation while keeping the desired behaviour is to override `onBackPressed()` for the *"three other activities"* (in fact, just for two of them) starting a previous `Activity`, i.e. the one you came to the current one from.